# Reliable browser/OS for use of showing webpage?

Tags: web-browsers, pi-b

I recently got a Raspberry Pi 1 Model B Revision 2 with the intention of using it as a kiosk-type device which refreshed a webpage every 2 minutes. It seems that every time I attempt to keep it running for more than a day with Raspbian and Midori/Epiphany it crashes/freezes one way or another. I need to keep it running forever, if possible. I have it configured to refresh just using the [website](http://refreshthis.com), which works fine, until the browser crashes/freezes. Has anyone here done a similar setup, and how did they make it work reliably?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this your website? Are there any errors in the logs?

Comment: I am using this to access one of my websites, yes, but it is most definitely not a problem with the website. I tried using an i7 desktop and it works fine there. Which logs are referring to, though?

Comment: There should be logs under /var/log/midori

Comment: Did you find any useful error logs?

Comment: Are you talking about Kiosk (with HID like keyboard or mouse) or DS (Digital Signage, no HID, just showing information)?  We run a serious lot of DS Pi's and in my personal experience the Pi (read: any Pi web browser) is not quite capable of running heavy/certain/special HTML5 pages.  Out of this frustration I opted for a slideshow with png/jpeg's, generated by Imagick.
Although I'd really prefer html above stills, I have given up on HTML since a while.

Answer (score 1):

If a full-screen web page is the only thing you want to use it for then [FullPageOS](https://github.com/guysoft/FullPageOS) might be a good choice.

The distribution uses chromium for this. So you could just install Chromium.

Comment: First thing I hear about this distro, I'm going to give this a try.

Answer (score -2):

I've used [uzbl browser](http://uzbl.org/) in the past with great success. However, raspbian is one of the worst distros however from personal experience. I suggest using arch linux for arm and running either nodm or dwm for your display manager.

The Following [guide highlights](http://mycomputerhelp.net/2015/09/23/best-modern-lightweight-web-browsers-for-linux-raspberry-pi-slower-computer/) most of the [process for raspbian](https://github.com/MobilityLab/TransitScreen/wiki/Raspberry-Pi) but it is just as easy to use arch linux-arm instead.